# Use environment appsettings.{Environment}.json vs hardcoding in file name or db connection details in CreateHostBuilder method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using ef core it's possible to get everything working and run the dotnet ef migrations command line tool but Program.cs required the method

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
```

The only thing that isn't ideal is storing database settings in a development json file then having to hardcode the development json file name in that method or hardcoding the db connection details into that method. When checking

```
context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() //always returns false
```

it is never correct or doesn't get set properly so we can't use context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName as a variable either. Is there a way in the CreateHostBuilder method to load the proper app settings json file and configure/setup the environment for running the ef migrations command line tools vs hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a few options to setup the Hosting Environment.

You can set a value of the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. This applies to all types of apps. Or you can setup `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable, as this overrides the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` when `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults` is called.

Another options is to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value in the `launchSetting.json` of your project.

While you can give any value to those environment variables, the framework provides the following values: "Development", "Staging", and "Production".

You can find more information about this in the [Use Multiple Environments in ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Already have the right environment in launchSettings.json and adding this doesn't work as the frst call to Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) :                 .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                }) so we always get Production and why I outlined it gives development environment as false in the above question